# Execute function from Html with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have this for example, which is a file html:

```
<html>

My html

<script>
    function Test() {
          alert("yaaaah");
    }
</script>

</html>
```

I want that nodeJS server execute the function Test() in a file which is at /path/here for example.

Use require doesn't work because the function is nested in the html.

How can I do to access to this function and execute it from server side?

Comment: Why are you writing functions in the frontend that must be executed by the backend?

Comment: If you were to extract the JS and run it, then it still wouldn't work because `alert` is a browser API and isn't available to Node. This reads like an http://xyproblem.info/ and you should probably explain what you really want to achieve.

Comment: @Diego The html file containing css and js is wrote by an user, to respect the norms (defined by me), he need to create function getHeight(), getWidth() of his iframe for example. (Each html file is iframe containing only input). And I need to get the value of the return function. I don't use document.windowContent.myFunction() because it needed that I allow "allow-same-origin" but i can't, for the security. So i wanted to used socket to execute this function, get the return value and send it to my general page (the parent). I don't know if i'm clear, ask questions and don't hesitate!

Comment: @Diego Or maybe if I can require the function nested in html It can work but how do that? Normally it's require(blablablah.js) because it's a js file. But if my desired function is in html file? Can't do let test = require(blablablah.html). So I can do test.getHeight(), and so on...

Comment: Why not doing everything on the frontend?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086722/resize-cross-domain-iframe-height

Comment: @Diego to let the developer of the iframe to specified its min-height, height and width of its iframes when it's displayed on the parent.

Comment: @Quentin I'm checking that

Comment: Suposing that parent is controlled by you, can't you create a function resizeIframe(), which resizes via jQuery the iframe, and force developers to call your function with the correct parameters.  All in frontend.

Comment: @Diego Oh, so you say, in parent there is a function resizeIframe(size). And for developpers, in their html (iframe), they will call the parent function resizeIframe with completing parameters? I think it's not possible to an iframe to call to a parent function (WITHOUT allow-same-origin)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the Iframe issue. I think now I understand your problem.

Comment: @Diego Cool for your understanding! :) If I could allow-same-origin, it will be so easier, but I can't let developpers acces to coockie, DOM, and so on..

Comment: @Erased — Did you read the the duplicate question? You can use message events to pass data between origins with JS without giving full access to cookies and the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be force them to write an specific comment inside the HTML something like:

```
<!--key 400,500-->
```

Then you can read the HTML file and extract the values with a RegExp:

```js
let html = '<html><!--key 500,23--></html>'

let matches = /<!--key (\d+),(\d+)-->/g.exec(html);
matches.shift();

console.log(matches);
```

Although, if width and height are not static then it's not a valid answer.

Comment: And what is the utility of this specific comment? I don't understand the utility. Yeah, it's not static.

Comment: "if width and height are not static" — It's a web page. They won't be static. They'll vary from system to system.

Comment: @Quentin It's not really the height and width for my project. It will be precisely min-height, max-height, min-width and max-width

Comment: @Erased Have you thought about implementing two socket.io connections, one from the iframe to the server and other from the server to the parent? I cannot imagine any other solution.

Comment: @Diego Then, in developer html file, they need to connect to socket IO, and so on.. It will be complicated and not sure that will working. :// Thanks a lot for your time, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Quentin Is it impossible to execute this function inside html by server nodejs?